# javascript array undefined value

Tags: javascript

```
var image= [];
var i;
var j;
function sendimg(img){
 alert(img.src);
 image[i]=img.src;
 i++;
}

function getimg(){
   document.getElementById("usershero").src = image[j];
   j++;
}
```

I have a set of 10 clickable images and every time someone clicks on one of the images the sending function is being called in order to get the `src` of the image which needs to be stored in an array for further use.
The problem is that I cannot store the value of the String variabe `img.src` in the array `image` and `alert(image[i])` is printing `undefined`.
Using `alert(img.src)` gives me the correct value.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. And are you using duplicate IDs?

Comment: `i` and `j` need to start with a value.

Comment: they do , my fault on the post

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should work :

```
var image= [];
    var i=0,j=0;

    function sendimg(img){
       image[i]=img.src;
       i++ ;
    }
```